# How to "de-nest" some nested lists

Tags: common-lisp, racket

I have a recursive function that gives me this answer:

```
'((()) (((((a c d f e d))))) (((((a c d e f d))))))
```

Besides the fact that I need to look through the function in order to clean it up, that raises me the question: how to clean this answer up? How to "de-nest" those lists in order to return this:

```
'((a c d f e d) (a c d e f d))
```

I need some strategy or appropriate function in Racket or in Common Lisp.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify a bit better what exactly do you want? Why not unflatter into `'(a c d f e d a c d e f d)` or `'(() (a c d f e d) (a c d e f d))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you want is a little bit unclear—if you just want to flatten a list, in Racket, you would just use the `flatten` function:

```
> (flatten '((()) (((((a c d f e d))))) (((((a c d e f d)))))))
'(a c d f e d a c d e f d)
```

However, it looks like you want to flatten each *sublist*, in which case you would want to just use `map` paired with `flatten`:

```
> (map flatten '((()) (((((a c d f e d))))) (((((a c d e f d)))))))
'(() (a c d f e d) (a c d e f d))
```

However, this still leaves the first empty list, which in your question it looks like you would like to remove. In that case, I would just add an additional `filter` step after flattening:

```
> (filter (negate empty?) (map flatten '((()) (((((a c d f e d))))) (((((a c d e f d))))))))
'((a c d f e d) (a c d e f d))
```

You could wrap this into a simple function that has the behavior you want:

```
(define (flatten-non-empty-sublists lst)
  (filter (negate empty?) (map flatten lst)))
```

Answer (score 3):

In common lisp, you can get the `flatten` function from [alexandria](http://quickdocs.org/alexandria/), which you can get from [quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).